# Kafka Stream Rock DB data is not getting deleted

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Kafka Rock DB data is not getting deleted .State directory size is goes on increasing .

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

rocksdb can generate LOG.old file when necessary,this file number is limited 1000 by default